# a media staple -- meaning?

Tags: meaning

Source: http://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-29793696

> The airport has become a symbol of Ukraine's fight against separatists, and the "cyborgs" are Ukrainians who have held on to it despite persistent rebel attack.
>   The nickname was first used online and has since become **a media staple** in Ukraine. It stuck, because to some the Donetsk airport defenders' exploits have appeared superhuman.

What does that actually mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO, the word *staple* here means common in use. We have another such word *staple food* means *the basic* food commonly eaten in a particular area.

The phrase means that the nickname has become a common term in media ever since it was used online for the very first time.